# First Scrapy Crawler

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I've been working through some courses on datacamp and reading the scrapy documentation. I've tried to make my first spider.

It is supposed to scrape the course names on the first page of datacamp.com and then save into a links.csv in the same folder as the script is in (on desktop).

Not quite working the way I want. Any help in what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class DC (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "DC"


def start_requests(self):
    urls = ['https://app.datacamp.com/learn/courses']
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"mfe-app-learn-hub-1tu8i8n")/text()]').extract()
    filename = f'links.csv'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.writelines([link + '/n' for link in links])


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(DC)
process.start()
```

Comment: Hi @tammyz - it will be helpful to have an example of the results you are getting and an explanation of what is wrong with the result.

Comment: For the CSV file you can use [FEEDS export](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html?highlight=feeds#feeds). But this website requires you to login, so you'll need to do this first.

Comment: Quick tip—to see what response Scrapy is getting, run this from your terminal:
`scrapy view https://app.datacamp.com/learn/courses`.
I see a Cloudflare page. 
As mentioned in one of the answer, for beginners, the best place to begin is https://books.toscrape.com/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the starting url is a poor choice - your spider is redirected to the login page. The website will only return the content you are looking for after you log in.

I'd suggest starting from the following website instead: https://books.toscrape.com/

If you only use the defaul behaviour in the `start_requests()` function (which you do)
you can settle on
`start_urls = ['https://app.datacamp.com/learn/courses']`

Your xpath selector is not actually extracting links - it doesn't mention any attributes.

`.extract()` method is outdated, use `.get()` instead ([docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first)).

It's a bad idea to create files from parse function - you will end up creating the same file multiple times on the same run. Instead, you should yield items like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    links = response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"mfe-app-learn-hub-1tu8i8n")/text()]').getall()
    for link in links:
        yield {"link": link}
```

The class name and the spider name are ambiguous.
If you update them, the code should look like this:

```
import scrapy

class DataCampSpider (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "datacamp"
    start_urls = ['https://app.datacamp.com/learn/courses']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//h2[contains(@class,"mfe-app-learn-hub-1tu8i8n")/text()]').getall()
        for link in links:
            yield {"link": link}
```

Use this command in the terminal `scrapy crawl datacamp -o datacamp_links.csv` ([docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-scraped-data))
to run the spider and write the output to a file.